# Firebase / incrementing id transaction demo bug?

Tags: firebase

Working on integrating Firebase in my app and currently exploring how to generate unique user ids using transactions.

The relevant demo (http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/5ESSp/) referenced on the official Firebase website (https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/examples.html) seems to have a problem :

Hitting the "increment" button repeatedly and fast enough seems to result in the counter incrementing but then not all the corresponding records seem to get recored in Firebase. As such, if two people sign up at the same time, isn't that going to mess up something ?

Here is the code available on jsfiddle :

```
var fb = new Firebase("https://katowulf-examples.firebaseio.com/incid/");

// monitors changes and updates UI
fb.child('counter').on('value', updateDiv);
fb.on('value', updatePre);

// creates a new, incremental record
$('#inc').on('click', incId);

// resets the data
$('#clear').on('click', function() {
   fb.remove(); 
});

// attempts to create any id you put in
$('#customButton').on('click', function() {
   addRecord($('#custom').val()); 
});

var errId = 0;
// creates a new, incremental record
function incId() {
    // increment the counter
    fb.child('counter').transaction(function(currentValue) {
        return (currentValue||0) + 1
    }, function(err, committed, ss) {
        if( err ) {
           setError(err);
        }
        else if( committed ) {
           // if counter update succeeds, then create record
           // probably want a recourse for failures too
           addRecord(ss.val()); 
        }
    });
}

// creates new incremental record
function addRecord(id) {
    setTimeout(function() {
       fb.child('records').child('rec'+id).set('record #'+id, function(err) {
          err && setError(err);
       });        
    });
}

// for demo purposes
function updateDiv(ss) {
   $('div').text(ss.val()||0);
   $('#custom').val('rec'+(parseInt(ss.val(), 10)+1)); 
}

// for demo purposes
function updatePre(ss) {
   $('#data').text(JSON.stringify(ss.val(), null, 2));  
}

// for demo purposes
function setError(msg) {
    var id = ++errId;
    $('body').append('<p id="err'+id+'">'+msg+'</p>');
    setTimeout(function() { $('#err'+id).fadeOut(); }, 2500);
}
```

Not sure what is going on and if this can be fixed ?

EDIT: I added a "for" loop to simulate 2 transactions coming from the client :

```
function incId() {
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {    

    // increment the counter
    fb.child('counter').transaction(function(currentValue) {
        return (currentValue||0) + 1
    }, function(err, committed, ss) {
        if( err ) {
           setError(err);
        }
        else if( committed ) {
           // if counter update succeeds, then create record
           // probably want a recourse for failures too
           addRecord(ss.val()); 
        }
    });
}}
```

RESULT:

{
  "counter": 2,
  "records": {
    "rec2": "record #2"
  }
}
Error: PERMISSION_DENIED

The 2 transactions get committed with the same value so 1 transaction is lost on the way as it gets refused for being a duplicate key. This does not seem to happen when done with two different browsers.

So this will only and always happen when both "simultaneous" transactions use the same Firebase object ?

Comment: It is unwise to rely on monotonically incrementing counters in a distributed environment. At best they limit concurrency, at worst they're unreliable. To generate unique ids, call `push`. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/push.html

Comment: Hi Frank. I edited the last part of my question. This only seems to happen when one same client has two simultaneous transactions.
I am reluctant to use push as I would like to generate some easy-to-share numerical IDs.